# After wrong submit redirects to wrong url

Tags: webforms

I have my form on page at url alias http://mypage.com/services. 
After wrong submission, form redirects me to http://mypage.com/services/formname - and every field is unordered, because Drupal doesn't read there template for this page. 
I want to after wrong submit drupal redirect me to same page, and list fields names that are required (and aren't filled).

Changing form options (eg. custom url) doesn't work too. It concerns only the case when all required fields are submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below ways :

1. Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events.

2. Using [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module.

> This module adds rules integration on webforms.